# cannot convert from String to Integer

Tags: java, aem, apache-felix

I have implemented some service which works fine. The service has the following property:

```
 @Property(name = MyService.PROXY_PORT, label = "Proxy Port", description = "Proxy Port", value= "8080")
    private static final String PROXY_PORT = "proxy.port";
```

I get the value of the `port` property as follow:

```
..
...
properties = context.getProperties();
String port = properties.get(PROXY_PORT).toString();
...
```

`port` in this case results `8080`. Now I would like to convert this String to Integer. I tried the following:

```
int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
int portInt2 = Integer.getInteger(port);
```

Both results null :(

What did I do worng?

Comment: does `port` has value in it ?

Comment: how can int be null

Comment: Put `System.out.println("**"+port+"**");` before `int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);` and tell us the output.

Comment: check if you are getting port value or not. and also check what exception you are getting ?
is it of numberFormat? or its nullPointer?

Comment: Check the string if it's null and trim its' space it if it's not null.

Comment: @StephaneM: this gives 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the port has a value and is not null then try:

```
int portInt = Integer.valueOf(port.trim());
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [PropertiesUtil](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/osgi/PropertiesUtil.html), an utility class created exactly for this case:

```
int port = PropertiesUtil.toInteger(properties.get(PROXY_PORT), 8080);
```

The second parameter is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Try if it work:

```
int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port+""); // check if the port value is coming or not before parse it.
int portInt2 = Integer.getInteger(port+"");
```

Comment: agree man, but it may be a case, same kind of problem was happening with me, with string parsing... so i try this way and it was working

Comment: This will yield a slightly different exception (if we have an exception at all, OP did not tell us), but not solve the problem.